# VB.Net WebBrowser Navigate Only Working Once

Tags: vb.net, browser

Hoping someone can help me with this.  I have two separate but related Forms, one of which contains a WebBrowser control.  The user fills out some information on Form 1 and clicks a button with the following code:

```
If Form2Shown = False Then
    Dim memoscreen As New Form2
    Form2Ref = memoscreen
    memoscreen.show()
    Form2Shown = True
    memoscreen.TopMost = OptionOnTop
Else
    Dim memoscreen As Form2
    memoscreen = Form2Ref
    memoscreen.TopMost = OptionOnTop
    memoscreen.QuickRefresh()
End If
```

The QuickRefresh sub in Form2 is the method that navigates.  It is called both when the form is loaded as well as manually in the code above:

```
Public Sub QuickRefresh()
    Dim HM As Form1
    HM = Form1Ref
    Me.Text = "retrieving information..."
    Me.AxWebBrowser1.Navigate("SomeValidURL")

    HM.Focus()
    HM.SetHugoFocus()
End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is that the first time QuickRefresh is called (i.e. when Form2 is loaded) the navigation is successful and the page displays fine.  If I then click the button on Form1 again, the page does not change.  The Text attribute and window focus does change however, so I know the method is firing.

Some things I've tried/checked:

- AllowNavigation is set to True on the WebBrowser control
- Have tried looping while the browser is busy while calling Application.DoEvents()

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Revisiting this, I noticed it has started working.  It is still not working on some users' machines however.  I haven't changed any code, but I did upgrade to IE9 from IE8.  I confirmed through searching that the WebBrowser control is affected by IE settings, but I'm not sure which one is causing this behavior.  Any insight as to which setting it might be?

Answer (score 0):

From your "Internet Options dialog > General Tab > Settings Button > Check for newer version of stored page" change that option to *Every Time I visit the webpage".  That setting impacts how the webbrowser control deals with the refreshing.

Answer (score -1):

Use the method refresh.

```
browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com") : browser.Refresh()
```